# WP7 - Problem with DataTemplate on emulator but not On Blend

Tags: windows-phone-7, datatemplate

This is the code:

```
      <ItemsControl x:Name="ContactsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ContactsControl, Path=DataContext.PageName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

On the TextBlock I want to get date from the ItemsControl data context, so I use ElementName and in the 'Path' I use Path=**DataContext**.PageName.

So, On Blend I can see the data on the TextBlock as it should be, but when I run the emulator I cant see the data... 
Why is it?

I'm working with VS2010 and Blend 4.

Thanks.

Comment: I presume that you're using design-time data in Blend.  Have you verified that this matches what you're using at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding an items control to a list of Contacts. Traditionally you will then bind the textblock to a property of the class contained in the list.  Why are you binding to another control and then bringing datacontext into the equation? Doesn't seem like something you normally do with a list.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer, this is legit Way to get data from the container for any propose. But the question here is nor why I'm doing so, but why does it not show on the emulator and do on Blend.